# get real ip for webserver in VM-Virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, nat

What i have:
Server with virtualbox, where via vagrant I setup a virtual machines. this VMs behind NAT virtualbox
In logs of web server I got this IP address 10.0.2.2

```
10.0.2.2 - - [19/Apr/2016:17:11:03 +0300] "GET /place/find-by-text?term= HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "********board" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

But for some reason I need to get a real IP address in my VMs webservers

I found that topics https://serverfault.com/questions/290116/how-to-get-virtualbox-nat-working-with-actual-client-ips where suggest use

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <your-vm name> --nataliasmode1 proxyonly
```

But it doesn't help, maybe I don't understood correctly, and I still see NAT virtualbox address 10.0.2.2

How to resolve this problem?

UDP: In access log of webserver(nginx for me) I want to see the real IP of client(like this 15.15.15.120) not address 10.0.2.2
UDP: My server have only one public IP and I don't have able to put VM into internet directly.

Comment: Was your VM shut down when you executed `.\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm vboxname --nataliasmode1 proxyonly`? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request out to the network to get the information:

```
curl http://ipinfo.io/ip
```

This has the added advantage of also getting the IP address of the internet facing host (in the case when your guest is double or triple NAT'd)

Comment: maybe I don't wrote correct ,sorry. In access log of webserver(nginx for me) I want to see the real IP of client(like this 15.15.15.120) not address 10.0.2.5

Comment: What you are seeing *is* the real IP of the client.  You are accessing the virtual server on a local network so the client has a local IP for that request.  The request doesn't traverse the internet, so there is no "internet ip" (which is, I suspect, what you want/need.)  The information mostly likely isn't even available (in any form.)